# SPServices SPGetLastItem returns last id for current user

Tags: list, jquery, spservices

The function `SPGetLastItem` from SPServices returns last id for items that only the current user has created. I want a function that returns the last id for any user.

Answer (score 1):

Well, adding the code below as a new function to the SPServices.js file, will work. The new function name is SPGetLastItemIdAnyUser :

```
// Function to return the ID of the last item created on a list. 
$.fn.SPServices.SPGetLastItemIdAnyUser = function(options) {

    var opt = $.extend({}, {
        webURL: "",         // URL of the target Web.  If not specified, the current Web is used.
        listName: "",           // The name or GUID of the list
        CAMLQuery: ""           // [Optional] For power users, this CAML fragment will be Anded with the default query on the relatedList
    }, options);

    var userId;
    var lastId = 0;


    // Get the list items for the user, sorted by Created, descending. If the CAMLQuery option has been specified, And it with
    // the existing Where clause
    var camlQuery = "<Query><Where>";
    if(opt.CAMLQuery.length > 0) {
        camlQuery += "<And>";
    }   

    camlQuery += "<Gt><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value></Gt>";


    if(opt.CAMLQuery.length > 0) {
        camlQuery += opt.CAMLQuery + "</And>";
    }   

    camlQuery += "</Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created_x0020_Date' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy></Query>";

    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        webURL: opt.webURL,
        listName: opt.listName,
        CAMLQuery: camlQuery,
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID'/></ViewFields>",
        CAMLRowLimit: 1,
        CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='Recursive' /></QueryOptions>",
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                lastId = $(this).attr("ows_ID");
            });
        }
    });
    return lastId;
}; // End $.fn.SPServices.SPGetLastItemIdAnyUser
```